# Created WebControl not working

Tags: presentation

I've created WebControl by extending `Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control` class and implemented the `DoRender` method. Adding either in another control or by adding to an XML file doesn't call the DoRender method at all. Possibly exist any config setting or something else?

```
using Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls;


namespace Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.HtmlControls
{
    public class UnorderedList : Control
    {
        public UnorderedList()
        {
        }

        protected override void DoRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write($"<h1>HelloWorld<h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Add to xml file not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<control xmlns:def="Definition" xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense">
  <WorkboxCommand>
    <Inline RollOver="true" Class="scRollover" Click="$Command">
      <ThemedImage Src="$Icon" Width="16" Height="16" Align="absmiddle" />
      
      <Literal Text="$Header"/>
    </Inline>

    <UnorderedList></UnorderedList>
  </WorkboxCommand>
</control>
```

Add by another webcontrol not working though Sitecore controls are working.

```
UnorderedList unorderedListControl = new UnorderedList();

webControl.AddControl(unorderedListControl);
webControl.Controls.Add(unorderedListControl);
rcontrol.Controls.Add(unorderedListControl);
```

Comment: Show some code, show screenshots from where you try to add it. Show Sitecore content tree with your new control

Answer (score 1):

To use custom controls you have to add namespace and assembly with your custom code to config in my case:

```
<controlSources>
<source assembly="Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" namespace="Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.HtmlControls" prefix="html" mode="on"/>
</controlSources>
```